# editting a taglib of a plugin. and then how to commit it to svn?

Tags: grails, plugins, commit, taglib

I had a change required in the taglib of plugin. the local system now shows change I required.
But what if I want to host it. I want to commit it. how do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to host your own version of plugin? Or commit to original repository and ask author to deploy plugin to Grails Central?

Comment: I want to host my version of plugin in my application. I couldnot find a way to commit it to svn.

Comment: I think it would be writtin gyour own tag then instead of using the plugin's as there was no method we could make our local version of plugin. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish plugin into your own Maven-compatible repository, see http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-release/docs/guide/plugins.html#custom